# GCC ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error when trying to compile old programs

Tags: c, makefile

I have a program wrote back when I was still at university, and it was running fine on ubuntu 16.04. Today I was trying to compile it on my Mac which is running OS version 11.2.3, and got the following error: "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64."

I did some research, it seems that this error is related to makefile, but I cant figure out what is wrong. Here is what I have in Makefile:

```
lander: lander.o
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o lander lander.o -lm -lncurses
lander.o: lander.c
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -c lander.c -g
clean:
    -rm -f *.o lander core
```

First time asking a question here, if the format of my text looks bad, I apologize in advance. Thank you.

Comment: The format of your text looks fine, but there isn't quite enough information here to answer your question. Would you be able to post the entirety of the error message?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Your question is OK, but we need some more context, like the exact error message, and if it references some source, that one also. Optimally show us a [example]. You might like to read "[ask]", too.